# Audit many-to-many relationship in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, audit

I have implemented listeners to audit changes to tables in my application using `IPreUpdateEventListener` and `IPreInsertEventListener` and everything works except for my many-to-many relationships that don't have additional data in the joining table (i.e. I don't have a POCO for the joining table).

Each auditable object implements an `IAuditable` interface, so the event listener checks to see if a POCO is of type `IAuditable`, and if it is it records any changes to the object.  Look up tables implement an `IAuditableProperty` inteface, so if a property of the `IAuditable` POCO is pointing to a lookup table, the changes are recorded in the log for the main POCO.

So, the question is, how should I determine I'm working with a many-to-many collection and record the changes in my audit table?

Edit: I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000

```
//first two checks for LastUpdated and LastUpdatedBy ommitted for brevity
else if (newState[i] is IAuditable)
{
    //Do nothing, these will record themselves separately
}
else if (!(newState[i] is IAuditableProperty) && (newState[i] is IList<object> || newState[i] is ISet))
{
    //Do nothing, this is a collection and individual items will update themselves if they are auditable
    //I believe this is where my many-to-many values are being lost
}
else if (!isUpdateEvent || !Equals(oldState[i], newState[i]))//Record only modified fields when updating
{
    changes.Append(preDatabaseEvent.Persister.PropertyNames[i])
        .Append(": ");
    if (newState[i] is IAuditableProperty)
    {
        //Record changes to values in lookup tables
        if (isUpdateEvent)
        {
            changes.Append(((IAuditableProperty)oldState[i]).AuditPropertyValue)
                 .Append(" => ");
        }
        changes.Append(((IAuditableProperty)newState[i]).AuditPropertyValue);
    }
    else
    {
        //Record changes for primitive values
        if(isUpdateEvent)
        {
            changes.Append(oldState[i])
                .Append(" => ");
        }
        changes.Append(newState[i]);
    }
    changes.AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: Digging futher into this, it appears my `OnPreUpdate` and `OnPreInsert` events aren't even firing when I modify the many-to-many collections, but the changes are being persisted to the database.  This is probably expected behaviour due to some deeper magic of NHibernate, but it feels like a bug/ommision to the unwashed masses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this won't fire is because the collections haven't changed, i.e. they're still the same instance of ICollection that was there before, however the content of the collections have changed.

I've looked for this myself, and the event listeners do not handle this situation. This may have been fixed for v3.0 (but don't quote me on that). There are a couple of non ideal workarounds:

1)Put a property on the object which makes a string representation of the collection for the purposes of auditing.

2)Make the items in the collection implement the interface so they are audited individually.

Edit: There is a third option:

"Rather than a many-to-many, I have a many-to-one going to the joining table, and then a one-to-many coming from it into the property table. I hide the joining table POCO behind the logic of each of the ends of the many-to-many joins, but still have to implement the object and all the interfaces on it."

Comment: I ended up using a 3rd option - create an explicit object for the joining table. Rather than a many-to-many, I have a many-to-one going to the joining table, and then a one-to-many coming from it into the property table. I hide the joining table POCO behind the logic of each of the ends of the many-to-many joins, but still have to implement the object and all the interfaces on it.  If this makes sense, you may want to add it to your answer (so it will be easier to read than in a comment)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that there actually is a way to do this via Event Listeners without having to expose the joining tables. You just have to make your event listener implement IPostCollectionRecreateEventListener or IPreCollectionRecreateEventListener. Based on my testing these events get fired for changed collections whenever the session is flushed. Here's my event listener code for the PostRecreateCollection method.

```
public void OnPostRecreateCollection(PostCollectionRecreateEvent @event)
        {
            var session = @event.Session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);
            var propertyBeingUpdated = @event.Session.PersistenceContext.GetCollectionEntry(@event.Collection).CurrentPersister.CollectionMetadata.Role;

            var newCollectionString = @event.Collection.ToString();
            var oldCollection = (@event.Collection.StoredSnapshot as IList<object>).Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
            var oldCollectionString = string.Join(", ",oldCollection.ToArray());

            if (newCollectionString == oldCollectionString || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newCollectionString) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldCollectionString)))
                return;

            User currentUser = GetLoggedInUser(session);
            session.Save(new Audit
            {
                EntityName = @event.AffectedOwnerOrNull.GetType().Name,
                EntityId = (int)@event.AffectedOwnerIdOrNull,
                PropertyName = propertyBeingUpdated,
                AuditType = "Collection Modified",
                EventDate = DateTime.Now,
                NewValue = newCollectionString,
                OldValue = oldCollectionString,
                AuditedBy = Environment.UserName,
                User = currentUser
            });
        }
```

The most tricky part is getting the name of the collection being updated. You have to chain your way through the PersistenceContext to get the Persister for the collection which gives you access to it's meta data.

Because none of these events or listeners are documented I don't know if this event gets thrown in other situations besides flush, so there's a potential it could create false audit entries. I plan to do some further research in that area.

Comment: "I plan to do some further research in that area." - any update to this?

Comment: I actually rolled off the project using this code a while ago. But we used it for a number of months without any obvious issues. No guarantees obviously